# E-Mail Validation with JavaScript & Error logging using Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, validation, email

The following code pushes "eMail" into the errors array even when a valid e-mail address is entered. What am I doing wrong?

```
if ( /^([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22))*\x40([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d))*$/.test( $("input[name=email]").val() ) != true ) errors.push("eMail");
```

Relevant HTML:

```
E-Mail Address:<br><input name="eMail">
```

Comment: Personally my "is valid email" check is much simpler `if(val.indexOf("@") >= 0)` - the point of validation on the client side is to save the server round trip and give people a short feedback loop so it makes sense to test for things they read wrong (like putting their name in the email fields)

Answer (score 0):

$("input[name=email]").val() is never a valid e-mail address because the actual name of the input is eMail, not email, meaning that the input value of email is always empty.
The regular expression can be found at http://badsyntax.co/post/javascript-email-validation-rfc822 or by Googling "RFC822 JavaScript E-Mail"

Comment: There was no way to deduce this from your question. There was no link between `errors` and the name. Moreover you should be using HTML5 email validation if possible anyway.

Comment: The error was simple but commonplace when using JQuery to reference elements on the page because JQuery never throws errors with unused element references. No, the error was not apparent from the code. Should I have posted the HTML as well?

Comment: Yes - You should have posted a self contained example containing relevant HTML and JS to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I added the relevant HTML to the question for future stackoverflow users to use as a reference. Hopefully it helps.